# Is there any way to undo a merge on geni.com?

Tags: geni.com

Someone in my family tree accidentally merged two accounts on [geni.com](http://geni.com), is there any way this can be undone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://help.geni.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=991:

> Please note that a Tree merger is
>   essentially the merging of two
>   profiles in different Trees into one
>   profile and Tree. Therefore, you can
>   undo a merge only before the profile
>   merger that connects the two tree has
>   been completed. Once that profile
>   merge has been completed, the trees
>   are merged.
>
> **Please note that once you have merged
>   your Trees it is irreversible.**
>   Therefore, it is important to pay
>   closely examine which information you
>   wish to keep, regarding each duplicate
>   Profile. If the trees are already
>   merged, you can use your Privacy and
>   Family Group settings to manage
>   privacy between the two sides of the
>   family.
>
> To reverse a merge, you will first
>   need to add the deleted profile back
>   to the Tree with the correct
>   relationships. Once that is done, you
>   can email help@geni.com with a link to
>   the merged profile and the incorrect
>   relationships that remain on that
>   profile.

Comment: That article was created in 2008, though, so I have no idea if that policy is still current.

Answer (score 0):

On the Geni wiki I read that they're planning a "Tree split" option which would probably solve your problem.

> Tree Merging is currently available.
>   Tree splitting [[1](http://forum.geni.com/topic.php?id=1789&replies=9#post-9620)] will enable existing trees to split.

On the other hand it says quite clearly:

> Once you have completed a merge:
>   It cannot be undone

Source: [Tree Merging](http://wiki.geni.com/index.php/Tree_Merging)